Movie with augmented reality
I forgot the name of a movie.
It was about a couple with a small daughter. The dad lived with the daughter and the mom was working somewhere else. The mother worked in a museum where she built a kind of artificial intelligence that could find out the story behind objects.
It was all set in a future with augmented reality, so when that was on everything looked cool but when it was off everything was made of white solid surfaces. They show a building from the outside and through the windows you can see how all the rooms look unique but then they turn it off and everything is blank.
At one point they all go to have dinner at a restaurant (the mother is not actually there, she is a hologram) that sells sushi and the girl starts playing with the fish that swims in the air. The girl also has a cat that is fake like that.
As I said, the mother is preparing an exhibition at the museum for the AI thing and many people connect to it from their own places by some kind of device that makes it feel like they are there (kind of like virtual reality).
The movie was definitely indie and I'm pretty sure it was in English. It should be quite new, I watched it 2 or 3 years ago.

Could it possibly be this one? http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3090670/?ref_=ttmi_tt

@followthemeow No, sadly it isn't

Please try to add anything that may help identification. What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

@Paulie_D Honestly that's all I remember

This sounds really interesting - if you come across it post the answer please

I believe the title you are searching for is Strange Beasts. This fits with many of the plot points and the fact that it is a British film produced after such BBC supported films such as Black Mirror and a couple or short films Sight, and Hyper Reality
https://www.theverge.com/2017/3/24/15048158/strange-beasts-cautionary-tale-ar-vr-short-film-watch

I checked the three shorts you mention and unluckily that's not what I remember at all, plus I'm pretty sure it was a full length movie.
